# App rejected by App Store due to some unknown bugs

Tags: ios

My app got rejected and it is showing this message:

It says it has bugs in iPad running, but I have only built the app for iPhone and not for iPad.
When I'm testing it on iPhone 5s having the same function it is working fine and in live tv I'm giving a url which gets down from the server some times and shows the message this event is currently not working.
How can these issues be resolved.

```
We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed oniPad running iOS 7.1.1 and iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.


The Live TV features does not work. 

    For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:

    - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
    - screenshots
    - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
    - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

    If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow as described in <https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/>Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce a crash or bug that only App Review or users are seeing.
```

Comment: Have you reported your issue to "Apple Developer Technical Support"?

Comment: No i have not reported to them yet.

Comment: will it help me in finding the bugs if i report them

Comment: yes maybe, they will let you know the exact scenario for your bug.

Comment: how to report them.Do i have to send them whole of my code

Comment: Checkout tis link https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/ for more info

Comment: Thanks alot..i'll just try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the information in the tech note that was mentioned in your rejection. This makes sure that you are testing the identical app that was sent to Apple. Debug builds may behave differently from Release builds for all kinds of reasons.

There may be something in your local environment that makes things work only on your network. Go to the nearest Starbucks and try the app there.

Your app may do things that crash when it is run first but fix things for the second run. Erase the app from your device before trying it.

You may know weak points of your app and avoid them subconsciously. Apple's testers don't. They *try* to break your app. Get someone to try out your app and pay them money for problems found so they *try* to find the problems.